# What are the purposes of pooling in CNNs?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, pooling

There are at least three questions on this site related to this

1. [What is the effect of using pooling layers in CNNs?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21532/2444)
2. [Is pooling a kind of dropout?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/9563/2444)
3. [What are the benefits of using max-pooling in convolutional neural networks?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/13580/2444)

I got the following useful information regarding the purpose of pooling. As per my understanding, the purposes of pooling, based on priority, in general, are as follows:

1. To decrease the size of the feature maps
2. To make the model stronger in feature extraction

Are there any other purposes of pooling in CNN other than them?

Comment: Without pooling, how do you recommend making the image smaller?

Comment: @user253751 It can be one of the purpose.